# How do the mechanical properties of 301 stainless steel, carbon fibre composites, and Aluminium-Lithium alloys compare?

Tags: materials, spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy, composite-materials

The design of Starship and its Super Heavy booster is based on the [reported](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOpMrVnjYeY&t=22m12s) fact that 301 stainless steel is advantageous to advanced carbon fiber composites and Aluminium-Lithium alloys at both cryogenic temperatures and re-entry temperatures.

**How exactly do the mechanical properties of these three materials compare over the temperature *range* from, say, -180 °C to 1500 °C?**

I think the most important properties are the yield strength and the Young's modulus. A plot of these properties over the whole temperature *range* would be very illustrative. Any other relevant characteristic is welcome, too.

For 301 stainless steel, please consider the hardened condition (cold rolled). For the carbon fiber material and the Aluminium alloy, I am not exactly sure how to specify further. Both should be certified or proven for aerospace applications.

A couple of search queries did not lead to the desired plot. Most scientific papers and industrial specifications seem to only state the material properties at certain discrete temperature values.

Comment: At the high end of your range, Al-Li is a liquid and carbon fiber has burned away. Both of these materials have to be protected from entry heating.

Comment: Maybe to inform this question a bit more, compare 301 SS to Al-Li 2196/2198 (External Tank / Falcon 9) and standard modulus carbon fiber? Maybe to add to add to  Organic Marbles beginning, at 1500 F your steel is starting to anneal and soften.

Comment: He said C not F.

Comment: @RokoMijic Yes. But that's not so important, the range was just a suggestion and can be discussed.

Comment: I think plotting this versus yield strength is what you are looking for. No one designs to ultimate tensile strength because it will have highly non-linear effects.

Comment: This link shows why. https://www.metalformingmagazine.com/assets/issue/images/2014/05/Science/Fig1.jpg

Comment: @KnudsenNumber of course, you're right. will edit.

Comment: Aluminium melts at ~660C, and carbon fibre reinforced plastics have a glass transition temperature somewhere in the 200s, making them structurally useless. Their cold temperature performance doens't really matter in this context if they can't survive reentry. What you're asking for probably only exists on the hard drives of companies with decent R&D departments.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer since it does not deal with the temperature range part of the question, but the graphic can't be presented in "comments"

For aerospace design, specific modulus (stiffness per mass) offers more insight into materials choice than Young's modulus or yield strength. Many materials fail due to deformation  before they yield.

[image]

In the diagram, carbon fiber reinforced plastics CFRP are shown having both a higher specific modulus  and higher specific strength than aluminum alloys.

In the real world, many other factors such as cost, corrosion resistance, manufacturing scalability, etc also need to be considered.